# Android studio handle multipe users. How can I modify the clickable parameter of a layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm a beginner developer developing an app for different user's layout.
In this app there are two kind of user, one that can read properties and one that can read and write properties as well.

I have to add several rows dynamically in the main layout and for this I use the inflate procedure.

here the row layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="sendMessage">

....
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now I want to change the clickable property to true/false depending on the kind of user. (if the user is a write user he can click on the layout to start a new activity and modify the properties of the row's objects).
Note that I want to use one activity to handle both users because in general I have to modify only a few properties like 3 clickable properties and 3 visible properties.
So I wrote these strings in the string.xml:

```
<string name="user_0_clickable">false</string>
<string name="user_1_clickable">true</string>
```

And I want to add dynamically the rows and change their clickable property depending on string "user_0_clickable" or "user_1_clickable" (passed by an intent after the login).
Is it possibile? And this is the best way for my scope if I have to change very few properties?

Comment: Your `User` object must be having a field specifying the type of user, is what I'm guessing. So what you can do is make a layout with all the possible components -> set all the components that are visible to all the users as visible in the XML and uneditable -> when you are dealing with handling the views, simply check the property for read/write for the `User` and then setVisible/Editable for the components. 
Basically use a `switch()` on the read/write field or whatever you have there to do this and this will make the code cleaner as well.

Comment: Is it possible do it like this way instead of the switch? `View myview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, false );
        myview.setClickable(getString(getResources().getIdentifier (string_user_by_intent)));
        mparent.addView(myview);` @ShankhadeepGhoshal

Comment: It'll be a lengthy on so I'll write it as an answer @July

Answer (score 1):

The view itself will have a clickable state, so in Kotlin:

`view.isClickable = false`

or in Java:

`view.setClickable(false);`

Based on the logic for the active user.

Answer (score 1):

Your `User` object will have some field like `userType` or `readWriteType` with some kind of either boolean or integer value like  0 or 1. So, in your `Activity` or `Fragment` or in the `ViewHolder` of the `Adapter` (if your are using `RecyclerView`) where you are basically setting data (something like `textView.setText("user.getName());`, etc.), simply do this:
`swich(user.getUserType())` (or do `switch(user.getReadWriteType())`, whatever field you use to indicate the state of read or write of the `User`)
and then:
`case userWrite: whateverTextField.setEditable(true); 
whateverButton.setClickable(true);
break;`
and then continue.
I don't think that there is a need for you to use the `string.xml` with `user_0_clickable` fields.
You don't need to dynamically inflate any component, just have all the components beforehand in your XML layout and simply by assign the `textFields` as not editable and buttons as invisible or non-clickable as per your requirement.